# Using ajax to get file size on file being uploaded via FTP - trying to prevent ajax from interrupting itself

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, filesize

I'm trying to check the progress of a file that is being uploaded by FTP with an ajax call that repeatedly echos the output of a bat file that checks the size of the file as it uploads. Namely I'm trying to make sure that once the ajax request has been sent over a UNC path that it won't be interrupted with another, hence the .done and .fail.

This had previously worked before the application was transferred over to UNC path but now despite the ajax "succeeding" I'm still getting nothing in response.

When I try the bat file manually it works but takes a while (10-15 or so seconds I believe) to run which leads me to think I'm having a problem with the ajax sending another call while the previous one hadn't finished.

I attempted to solve this by using .done and .fail with the ajax request but I am apparently missing something. If anyone could point me in the right direction or explain to me where I'm going wrong it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your help!

Code example:

```
function getSize(f){
        $.ajax({
            url: "php file handling the ajax request",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                file : encodeURIComponent(f),
                }
            })
        .done(function(data){
                console.log("Ajax success");
                var percent = (data / s) * 1000;
                if(Math.round(percent) != 1000){
                    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar( "option", "value", Math.round(percent) );
                }
        })
        .fail(function(data){
            if ( data.responseCode ){
              console.log( data.responseCode );
            }
            console.log("Ajax failure");
        });
    }
```

***As of right now I'm getting the "Ajax success" console message but not getting anything back in data.***

***Update***
Cornelis just pointed out that I should try GET instead of POST. This had the interesting effect of getting me a return response of -2 instead of nothing. Progress!!

Comment: Since you're getting a 'Success' message that suggests your AJAX is working, so maybe the server-side script isn't returning what you expect. In any case, this is a clumsy way to do things. You can add an event listener to the Ajax 'onprogress' event and get the progress directly from that - no server call required.

Comment: I wasn't aware that would work with a file that is being uploaded from a client's machine to server via FTP. I must have misread something.

Comment: No - I misread your question. It won't work with FTP. This begs the question: why not transfer the file with an Ajax post over HTTP?

Comment: I was so excited for a second lol. Because I'm trying to fix something for a bud that is already up and running and is already a bit of a mess. Trying to change as few things as possible in this giant house of cards.

Answer (score 1):

Try using GET instead of POST

```
function getSize(f){
        $.ajax({
            url: "php file handling the ajax request",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                file : encodeURIComponent(f),
                }
            })
        .done(function(data){
                console.log("Ajax success");
                var percent = (data / s) * 1000;
                if(Math.round(percent) != 1000){
                    $( "#progress_" + id ).progressbar( "option", "value", Math.round(percent) );
                }
        })
        .fail(function(data){
            if ( data.responseCode ){
              console.log( data.responseCode );
            }
            console.log("Ajax failure");
        });
    }
```

Comment: And that change will make _what_ difference?

Comment: Well I'm getting a -2 instead of nothing now lol. So its progress!

Comment: @gv0000 Where is the data you are trying to get? And can you give a quick exampel of the data.

Comment: The data comes from a bud's employee that uploads it to a server via this application. Could be anything from a pdf to a video interview. It worked fine before he decided to switch over to a UNC path but now it takes quite a bit of time to run.